# Creating a Facebook app with python using Google App Engine

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine

I am new to here. I am working on a python project using Google App Engine. The project is about getting information from facebook (whoever logged in from the app). Just want to access the user's own information. Don't need to post, comment or upload photos.

So far, I have already looked at pythonforfacebook or sth similar. They all wants me to create access token and secret key. I think I will need those only if I want to make changes.

Let me rephrase, my app is just to browse information. Is there any other api that I can use without getting access token?

Thanks.

Comment: Firstly, your title is  unhelpful as this question does not appear to have anything to do with GAE, but with Facebook. Secondly, you will always need an api key to access Facebook programmatically: why don't you want to create one? It's not exactly complicated.

Comment: I already have one. Just curious, why do I need to get the api key? Also, I am confusing with google app engine and facebook apps. I thought I needed to create a facebook app if I want to deploy on facebook. Can someone explain me about it?

Comment: I am using python for facebook. let say if I put in my api key, can other users log on to the app and access their own information?